# Color terrain above a certain altitude with MapKit?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm working on a project with SwiftUI and MapKit and I would need to display a map that highlights terrain within a given boundary and above a given altitude.

The end result should look like this, where I can give a different color to each altitude range.

[image]

I think I could use a custom marker if I knew the altitude and the boundary, but I would have to programmatically/manually define the shape, with holes and such, and performance would be terrible.

Does MapKit provide a way to do what I'm after?

Comment: The classical UIKit MapKit supports MKTileOverlay: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay. You basically provide your own map from a map tile server. That is one of several things that SwiftUI MapKit can't do.